# Align buttons to line up with fieldset

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

Background:The website I am working on there are several different filters that people can use in order to show only the data they need; basic stuff. To make things look nice since I am not css inclined, I am using bootstrap to make things look clean.

Problem: I can't seem to get the buttons to line up with the right side of the fields. I can make them pull to the very edge of the field set, I can make push/pull them to the general area they should be in, but I can't get them to line up nicely and stay that way regardless of how you rearrange the size of the page window.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v3cugpx1/1/

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
        <div class="pull-right">
            <a class="btn btn-info" href="#" title="Clear"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></i> Clear</a>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" title="Filter" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i> Filter</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

It's important to match the nesting of columns because of the gutters in the grid, which the other answers remark upon. If you start with the other two answers, it's easy enough to modify them to add the margin between the buttons you're looking for:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="btn-toolbar col-md-12">
      <a class="btn btn-info pull-right" href="#" title="Clear"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></i> Clear</a>
      <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" title="Filter" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i> Filter</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The only really real addition is the `btn-toolbar` class to the inner-most div. And for posterity here's the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5chrkb3t/3/).

Comment: This works perfectly when there is only one column, but when there are two columns the buttons will be moved in from the edge slightly. You can see it in the jsfiddle you linked when you stretch the pane out wider. Any thoughts how to fix it then?

Comment: It would appear that the difference is exactly 5px from my quick testing. No idea what causes it.

Comment: See [this update](https://jsfiddle.net/5chrkb3t/5/). Annoyingly the btn-toolbar class has a `margin-left: -5px` to it which causes that to happen. Not entirely sure why it only takes place when you hit a two-column mode, but I'm not that invested in finding out (sorry!). In the fiddle I just set the style for the one element to have `margin-left: 0`, but you might choose to have a `marginless-btn-toolbar` or something similar instead.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `.input-group` instead use `col-sm-*` classes to give extra padding multiple times, so that you can match the padding available on all other form elements. And then arrange the buttons inside of it, like:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12"> <!-- Extra Padding (15px) -->
  <div class="col-xs-12"> <!-- Extra Padding (15px) -->
    <div class="col-xs-12"> <!-- Extra Padding (15px) -->
      <a class="btn btn-info" href="#" title="Clear"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left pull-left"></i> Clear</a>
      <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" title="Filter" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i> Filter</button>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Have a look at the updated **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v3cugpx1/3/)**.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrapper cols for the inputs. I included one "col-md-12" before the button's "form-group" and another one after it. This way your code stay consistent and you achieve what you want.

```
<div class="col-md-12"> <----
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-12"> <----
            <div class="input-group-btn">
```

Updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v3cugpx1/4/)

Comment: Yeah but when you have it like that there is no space in between the two buttons and it looks cramped.

Comment: The original fiddle is like that. He didn't ask for any spacing between the buttons. Anyways, it's not hard to add some margin between them.